# No appropriate python interpreter found. - Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am new to Cassandra . I  installed Cassandra in RHEL 6.5 , and installed Cassandra 3.5 . 
When launch the cqlsh , it gives me the error 
No appropriate python interpreter found.

What could be the reason , should I try a lower Cassandra version ? any one encountered the same issue ?

Answer (score 2):

If your Python version is below 2.7, you should upgrade it to at least Python 2.7.
It might be a version between 2.4.x and 2.6.x.

Cassandra versions 3 and greater need at least Python2.7